# How can I call two src/url request with iframe or add one iframe into another iframe?

Tags: jquery, iframe, frameset-iframe

How can I call two src/url request from "iframe". I need to show two src/url with iframe. I am calling one file with iframe src...but how can I call second file? or can I add one iframe within another iframe?

Thanks

Comment: what you already try to do? the question is not clear, please add more details ...

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one URL per iframe.

Your alternatives are:

1. embedding iframes
2. two sibling iframes (have two iframes right next to each other, each with a URL)

Comment: Thanks kamasheto, But I can not keep the two iframe next to each other. I need to call one js/css file in first iframe and html files in another iframe which call first iframe js/css file. I am calling both files from remote domain. For "embedding iframes" I will go through it. Thanks for quick reply :)

Comment: Are you sure you need iframes? You could do that without the need for iframes. Link to your remote CSS/JS from your single document, and have your html use the media as you wish.

Comment: kamasheto, Can you brief me how I can do that..if you have any example. pls let me know